# Is it possible to pass ProgressDialog through Bundle?

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-bundle

I am stuck in a situation where I want to pass a ProgressDialog object through bundle.

```
ProgressDialog PD =  new ProgressDialog();
PD.setMessage("My message");
PD.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
PD.show();

// some other code

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("someVal1", textValue);
bundle.putInt("someVal2", integer_name);
bundle.put..... // pass PD here?
```

I have searched the web but could not find any useful answers.

Comment: A very bad idea. Even if you could, you'd leak memory

Comment: ya..really bad idea!!

Comment: Alexander Zhak is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProgressDialog is too complex to pass it with Bundle. You should save PD's parameters (title, message, progress) and restore the values in a new ProgressDialog.